# Android MediaPlayer/VideoView: event callback to fire when a certain play time is reached?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-videoview

I'm working on a video player that plays adverts at certain points in  a `video`, however I've been looking through the android documentation and there doesn't seem to be an event listener to tell me when a `MediaPlayer` has reached a certain point in the play time.

I've worked around it at the moment by making a `Runnable()` that calls `getCurrentPosition()` to see if my play time target is reached, and the runnable is posted to a handler every second, but this approach is obviously not ideal, is there a way to set up a callback when a certain play time is reached?

If not, is there a better way to detect if a play time is reached other than how I am doing it?

Comment: Are you using MediaController for your video ? If so it has seekbar you can get it and set setOnSeekBarChangeListener on it. Please share your code i will modify it.